# How do I prove that $\dim(V+W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W)?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

How do I prove that $\dim(V+W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W)$, where $V$ and $W$ are subspaces? The base of $V$ is given as $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_r\}$ and the base of $W$ is given as $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_m\}$. $V\cap W = \{0\}$ is also given.

I've proved in a previous part that $S$, the set that contains the vectors in the bases of $V$ and $W$ is linearly independent. I am not sure how to prove $\dim(V+W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W)$ since the only way I've previously proved this sort of problem is by showing the number of non pivot columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set $S=\{v_1,\dots, v_r,w_1,\dots w_m\}$ is linearly independent (as you proved already) and also generating. This means it is a basis. The dimension of a vector space equals the number of basis vectors needed to span it. This is $r+m$ in your case. Consequently, $\dim(V+W)=r+m$. Now, since $\{v_1,\dots, v_r\}$ is a basis for $V$, $\dim(V)=r$ and likewise for $W$. This proves your assertion.

Comment: Wow, thank you! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify, what is a generating set?

Comment: We call a set $A$ generating for a vector space $V$, if every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of elements in $A$. In other words, if $V=\operatorname{span}(A)=\{\lambda_1a_1+\dots+\lambda_r a_r\mid \lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r\in k\}$, where $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_r\}$ and $k$ is the ground field (most likely $k=\mathbb R$ or $k=\mathbb C$ in your case).

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: yep, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that
$$
Dim(W+V)=Dim(W)+Dim(V)-Dim(W\cap V).
$$

This fact should be demonstrated in your textbook.

Comment: Hey, can you explain how $W + V$ is defined? Aren't they sets?

Comment: @MarcelB yes, they are sets, but they have a sum structure on them. This allow me to define their sum: if $V$ and $W$ are vector subspaces, $V+W$ will be the set of all possible sums $v+w$, where $v \in V$ and $w\in W$. It's a good fixing exercise to check that $V+W$ is a vector subspace and that $V$ and $W$ are proper subspaces of $V+W$. Do note, however, that "$V+W$" is just a notation and there is no general operations over subspaces (something like, the opposite of a subspace $V$ is $-V$ ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marra!